# How do I configure Opera so it selects the new tab when I command-click a link?

Tags: opera, browser-tabs

I'm trying to switch from Firefox to Opera just to see if I like it.  In Firefox, there are options so that when I command-click a link a new tab opens AND it is selected.  I can't find that in Opera (Opera 24).  A command-click opens a new tab but it is not selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to configure Opera to change this behavior.

- `Command–Shift–Click` opens the link in a new foreground tab.
- `Command–Click` opens in a new foreground tab.

This is a design decision to be aligned with the other browsers’ default on Mac. In other words, what the majority of users would expect to happen.

If you feel really strongly about changing this, it can be achieved using the [Opera extension API](https://dev.opera.com/extensions/). Monitor when new tabs are created (`onCreated`) and activate it (`update(active)`) to make it the foreground tab. You can get more help with extensions in the [Opera extension forum](https://forums.opera.com/categories/en-opera-add-ons).